Undefined eventHandler Jasmine js
I tried to make a small application that just counts vowels, words, and shows the text without vowels. it all works like i want it to. whenever i try to run tests on it with Jasmine.js, it returns "Error during loading: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') in http://localhost:8888/src/script.js line 27", im pretty sure the problem is that the index isnt loaded in the jasmine spec file, but cant seem to find on how to fix this. this is my jasmine spec file:


describe("The word app: ", function () {
    it("counts words", function () {
        const sentence = "een twee drie vier vijf";

        const result = getWordCount(sentence);

        expect(result).toBe(5);
    });
    it("does not count whitespace", function () {
        const sentence = "een twee     drie";

        const result = getWordCount(sentence);

        expect(result).toBe(3);
    });
    it("removes vowels", function () {
        const sentence = "test one two three";

        const result = removeVowels(sentence);

        expect(result).toBe("tst n tw thr");
    });
    it("does not count consonants", function () {
        const sentence = "test one two three";

        const result = getVowelCount(sentence);

        expect(result).toBeLessThan(9);
    });
    it("counts vowels", function () {
        const sentence = "test";

        const result = getVowelCount(sentence);

        expect(result).toBe(1);
    });
});



And a snippet of my index/script.js


let text = document.querySelector("#text-area");
const klinkers = document.querySelector(".klinkers");
const woorden = document.querySelector(".woorden");
const nieuweTekst = document.querySelector(".nieuwe-text")
console.log(text, klinkers, woorden, nieuweTekst)
function getWordCount(sentence) {
    const words = sentence.trim().split(/\s+/);
    return words.length;
}
function getVowelCount(sentence) {
    let count = 0;
    const words = sentence.trim().split(/\s+/).join('');
    const letterArr = [...words];
    letterArr.forEach(letter => {
        if ("aeiou".includes(letter)) {
            count++;
        }
    });
    return count;
}
function removeVowels(sentence) {
    const vowelsRegex = /[aeiouAEIOU]/g;
    const sentenceWithoutVowels = sentence.replace(vowelsRegex, '');
    return sentenceWithoutVowels;
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    text.addEventListener("input", () => {
        try {
            klinkers.innerHTML = getVowelCount(text.value);
            woorden.innerHTML = getWordCount(text.value);
            nieuweTekst.innerHTML = removeVowels(text.value);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    });
})
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Teller</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Voer hier je tekst in:</h2>
        <textarea name="" id="text-area" cols="30" rows="15"></textarea>
        <p class="counters">Aantal klinkers: <span class="klinkers"></span></p>
        <p class="counters">Aantal woorden: <span class="woorden"></span></p>
        <p class="counters">Nieuwe text: <span class="nieuwe-text"></span></p>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



Long story short, can anyone confirm if the problem is that the index hasnt been loaded in jasmine, and if so, how to fix this?
